# SQLite not connecting on newly created pages

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite, core-data

I am dumbfounded. In both xcode 3 and 4 I am able to connect to my sqlite DB on pages I did a month ago. With any new view / class I create i get a null value returned. Even if I copy word for word a page that is working and returning my data.

Has anyone else had this happen to them? Have there been any fixes you might have tried.

Comment: I think you may need to improve on the question with sample code, and also telling us what "pages" mean.

Comment: Hi Kendall
Yeah. I am sorry. Just frustrated.

I am not sure what sample code to add as it is such a weird error. I have a tableview that works (it is able to pull data from my sqlite and coredata files). I copy that tableview almost word for word (with obvious differences to make the file work) and it returns a nul from the db. Is there a change in the plist or framework that might have allowed previous files to work and not new ones?

Comment: I had PLENTY of things happening going beyond my understanding when using CoreData. One learning I took out of it, whenever weird things start happening, make sure you do a deep-clean (remove build-folder and remove any user-specific part from xcodeproj-folder and remove the entire app folder from the simulator).

Comment: Clarification: Are you using a mix of SQL and Core Data or just Core Data with an sqlite store? It sounds like the former.

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of any changes that would cause this problem. My older code still works fine and I seen no similar reports.

The wording of your question suggest that you are thinking of Core Data in SQL terms which is dangerous. Core Data is an object graph management system with persistence options. It's a lot more than just a database. It is very common for people to get confused into errors by trying to treat Core Data as just an object wrapper around SQL.